# BigQuery updating regular field with record field

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, nested

I have a table with few regular fields and one repeated record field:
`batch_number<INT64>, data array(start_date<DATE>, end_date<DATE>, ...)`. I am trying to update `batch_number` field based on condition in the nested field. But my update changes all rows in the table:

```
UPDATE ds.table as t
SET batch_number = 2
FROM ds.table i, UNNEST(data) as u
WHERE u.start_date = '2021-03-04'
```

Why is this and what is proper syntax in my case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following SQL:-

```
UPDATE ds.table 
SET batch_number = 2 
WHERE '2021-03-04' IN (SELECT start_date FROM UNNEST(data))
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for!